# Nature of indivisible particles of matter

Tags: particle-physics

Matter is something which has mass and occupy space . So it's indivisible particle must also occupy space . If it occupy space then it must have some boundary surface which encloses its volume . If realy those particles have volume , then what is the charisteristics of the boundary surface? And how do one particles interact with the boundary surface of other wall?

Comment: this shows complete ignorance of the nature of *elementary* particles in main stream physics of today, which are point particles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle

Comment: You said exactly what I want to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking ordinary matter as our example:

an atom consists of a tiny nucleus surrounded by electrons, like a cloud of bees surrounding a flowering plant. the average distance of the bee cloud from the flower defines the "boundary" of the atom, so there is no hard "wall". Nearby atoms therefore interact with each other via the electric fields created by their electron clouds.

Comment: You provided the estimate of size of atoms. But still there is 1 question unclear to me that is how to estimate the size of electrons protons and neutrons or any particle that makes them individualy?

Comment: @ sanjoy, this has accurately been done in particle accelerators by shooting electrons at protons and neutrons and measuring the angles at which they scatter off the target. Protons and neutrons have a well-defined diameter but electrons are point particles with no size at all.

Comment: Does Well defined diameter mean it is not any approximate or average diameter ?

Comment: @SanjoyKundu, search on "deep inelastic scattering".

Comment: I searched for it. It is a significant process in particle physics which is used to probe the inside of particles like neutron and proton. It proves that neutrons and protons are divisible . But I want a discussion on indivisible particles of matter.

Comment: Electrons are indivisible and also point particles. The fact that I want to confirm is that all indivisible particles are point particles.

Comment: that is indeed correct.